# Embedded database with saving feature on C# WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, database

I will need to build a C# WPF application with an embedded database (so user does not need to install a database or a database server). My application have concurrently insertion (up to 50) and each 50 of these insertion could occur concurrently every 10ms (so in 10ms I get 50 different data into the same Table).

I will then need to save all these datas together with some setting (e.g. TextBoxes) to a file so I open these data and setting values to the application at a later time.

I am new to database - is SQLite good enough as an embedded database for such application? Does MySQL or PostgreSQL offer something embedded? And can I save a bunch of database data to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or [SQL Server Compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) would both work fine for this, from the sound of your requirements.

[VistaDB](http://www.vistadb.net/) is another potential option, if you want to use the same syntax as SQL Server but need >4GB (CE's limitations).